# Regular expression substitution Python

Tags: python, regex, text, substitution

I am having trouble with this one. I am trying to get a better handle on RE but it is not working. I have a list of strings that I want to erase if they are found in another string.

this is the exclusion list:

```
exclusionList = ['\+','of','<ET>f.','to','the','<L>L.</L>','f.','in','and','see','a','<L>Fr.</L>','as','<ET>ad.','<ET>a.','<PS>v.</PS></XR>',
             'from','<CF>ab</CF>','or','n.','<L>OFr.</L>','pple.','away','was','with','off,','pa.','on','is','cf.','stem','ad.','which',
             'by','action','ppl.','Cf.','but','<L>Gr.</L>','be','after','=','The','form','for','an','<XR><RX>prec.</RX></XR>',
             '<PS>a.</PS></XR>','<L>Eng.</L>','<PS>pref.</PS>','also','L.</L>','<XR><XL>a-</XL>','<XR><XL>-ing</XL><HO>1</HO></XR>.</ET>',
             'vb.','See','In','<L>OE.</L>','used','it','see','this','not','<PS>prep.</PS><HO>1</HO></XR>','has','a','so','early','s']
```

And this is what I am using to remove those words:

```
first_word = re.sub(r'\b'+exclusionList[a]+'\b', '',first_word)
```

where first word is a string read from a text file. I know this is going to be simple but I just do not quite get how to use RE very well.

Thanks

Comment: What's the content of the variable `a`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can only guess, but probably you want something like this:

```
pattern = r'\b({})\b'.format('|'.join(map(re.escape, exclusionList)))
first_word = re.sub(pattern, '', first_word)
```

Note that I'm escaping the words, so they will be matched literally, instead of being interpreted as regular expressions (which they don't seem to be).

Comment: Same idea as mine, but better realized.  +1.

Comment: @MarkReed Nothing better, only a lot of clarity sacrificed for a really tiny performance improvement.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: Don't see what you mean. I put readability before anything else here.

Comment: @NiklasB. I'm talking about the superfluous `compile`, and `map` to which I prefer generator expressions.

Comment: @BlaXpirit: "to which I prefer generator expressions." Well I don't. I prefer `map` over genexprs in these simple cases. Maybe that's because I like my code to fit into an editor line. Also, the call to `re.compile` helps separate the concerns here (formulating the pattern vs. matching). Of course it can be left away, shouldn't be a challenge to restructure it to whatever is needed.

Comment: I used a list comprehension below only because I was making a conscious effort to be idiomatically Pythonic, which is not my native mode.  I normally sling `map` around like crazy, but in Python, I prefer `map` when you have a named function to call, but prefer list comprehensions to the use of `lambda`.  I also find the use of `.format` clearer than my string concatenation.

Comment: @Mark: I think a lot of Python devs actually avoid `map` in favor of generator expressions (it's not a list comprehension if there are not square brackets :). I'm not one of them, but maybe I'm not representative (I'm primarily a Haskell hacker).

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick all at once:

```
exclusionRegex = r'\b(' + '|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in exclusionList) + r')\b'
first_word = re.sub(exclusionRegex, '', first_word)
```

**EDIT**: This is my test script:

```
import re

exclusionList = ['\+','of','<ET>f.','to','the','<L>L.</L>','f.','in','and','see','a','<L>Fr.</L>','as','<ET>ad.','<ET>a.','<PS>v.</PS></XR>',
             'from','<CF>ab</CF>','or','n.','<L>OFr.</L>','pple.','away','was','with','off,','pa.','on','is','cf.','stem','ad.','which',
             'by','action','ppl.','Cf.','but','<L>Gr.</L>','be','after','=','The','form','for','an','<XR><RX>prec.</RX></XR>',
             '<PS>a.</PS></XR>','<L>Eng.</L>','<PS>pref.</PS>','also','L.</L>','<XR><XL>a-</XL>','<XR><XL>-ing</XL><HO>1</HO></XR>.</ET>',
             'vb.','See','In','<L>OE.</L>','used','it','see','this','not','<PS>prep.</PS><HO>1</HO></XR>','has','a','so','early','s']

exclusionRegex = r'\b(' + '|'.join(re.escape(word) for word in exclusionList) + r')\b'
first_word = 'This is a test of the regex'
print re.sub(exclusionRegex, '', first_word)
```

And this is the output:

> This   test   regex

Comment: Yup, indeed.  Thanks, Niklas and BlaXpirit.

Comment: Thanks Mark,I am getting a syntax error at re.sub. Any suggestions

Comment: @EnglishGrad - re.sub is an expression, not a statement; you have to assign it to something or otherwise use it.  See my edit.